# magento Remove Ghost products

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I am am trying to configure a magento store . I have a couple of ghost products that appear on the Front end. These Ghost products have no name, no image , and aren't found under my back-end product list.  However their add to button is active and works and also has a wishlist URL in the form of.

```
example.com/wishlist/index/add/product/4/form_key/p3jZL1nym3j4XeNl/
```

I think I got myself into this mess after trying to duplicate a few products. How do I trace and get rid of these ghost products. Im using absolute template.

Answer (score 0):

Do you using the flat tables? If yes then try to reindex it.
P.S. check the product ID: 4 (in the backend).

Comment: Both Use Flat Catalog Category and product are set to "NO". I have a product with an id of 4 in the backend that shows perfectly well in the frontend. Hence could have some sort of a duplicate. As re indexing Ive done that a number of times.

Comment: It is very strange problem. The problem can be caused by the wrong data in the database, or some sort of the cache. Sorry but without access to your system I can not help to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna delete products with blank(null) product name & images
You can try

```
$products=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
    foreach($products as $key => $pId)
    {
        $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pId);
        if($product->getName()=='' && $product->getMediaGalleryImages()=='')
        {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pId)->delete();
            echo "successfully deleted product with ID: ". $pId ."<br />";
        }
        else{ echo "Could not delete product with ID: ". $pId ."<br />"; }
    }
```

You can also try deleting products which dont have imgs using

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array('_gallery_table' => $collection->getTable('catalog/product_attribute_media_gallery')),
        'e.entity_id = _gallery_table.entity_id',
        array()
    )
    ->where('_gallery_table.value IS NULL');
$collection->delete();
```